# Efficient find and replace pattern in body text using regular expression

Tags: jquery, html, regex, replace

What I am trying to do is replace a url and pattern e.g. `###http://www.google.com###` with the link wrapped by a `<a>` tag e.g. `<a href="http://www.google.com">Go There</a>`

The problem I face is that this url and pattern can appear anywhere in my webpage and It's containing element is always different - here is what I've done.

```
$('body').contents().each(function(){

  // Find the pattern.
  var element = $(this);
  var go_link = element.text().match("###(.*)###");

  // Replace the pattern with go there button.
  if(go_link && go_link[1] != '(.*)'){
    var pattern = go_link[0];
    var link = go_link[1];
    element.html(element.html().replace(pattern,'<a class="go_there_button" href="'+link+'">Go There</a>'));
  }

});
```

This works http://jsfiddle.net/84T9u/ but I feel that it is slightly inefficient as it has to iterate over every element in the `<body>` and there could be hundreds of these link patterns across each page of my site.

I have started to look at using the `:contains()` selector, I have found some answers on SO that extend this method to allow the use of regex, however I don't know enough about how the `:contains()` method works. Would it be any more efficient, or is it very similar in functionality to the `.each()` that I am using - iterating over all elements to find the desired text or pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
$('body').contents().each(function(){

  // Find the pattern.
  var element = $(this);
  if(element.html()){
      element.html(element.html().replace(/###(.*)###/g,"<a class=\"go_there_button\" href=\"$1\">Go There</a>"));

  }

});
```

OR Simply :

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/###(.*)###/g,"<a class=\"go_there_button\" href=\"$1\">Go There</a>"));
```

Comment: This is helpful, however doesn't really answer my question regarding the `:contains()` selector.

Comment: with :contains() we can select only the root element , but with 'each' we can access each children .

Comment: Yeah I think your second example is what I was looking for, it avoids iterating over each element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate or use any heavy XML methods, just change the HTML as a string:

```
str = str.replace(/###(https?:\/\/.*?)###/gi, '<a class="go_there_button" href="$1">Go There</a>');
```

Comment: Looks like `replaceAll` is used differently, and it shoulden't have a capital R - [http://api.jquery.com/replaceall/](http://api.jquery.com/replaceall/)

Comment: @Wezly oops. Confused with java. Try the edited version.

Comment: Now the forward slashes in the regex are breaking the JS. apart from that it is pretty much the same as Sujiths 'or simply' example, thanks anyway!

Comment: There's a subtle but very important different. His regex is a greedy one, so if two urls appeared near each other, it would mess up the output.

Comment: My site will only ever have one url inside the pattern tho `%%%/url/%%%` and you have also assumed that it will have `HTTP` at the start. no?

Comment: http or https, yes (btw I fixed the problem with unescaped slashes)