# Is there a way to replace a part of text with <img src> inside <p>?

Tags: jquery, html, image, text, replace

What I'm trying to do is to force this code to replace a part of the text that is ':•:' if he finds it on the page in a paragraph, with an image.

```
$("p").each(function () { 
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(':•:').html('<img src = "http://lilpic.png" />')); 
    } 
});
```

But what I ended up with was that the text was indeed replaced, but not with the image as it is, but with just ugly raw HTML-code of it. What am I doing wrong?
What I need in the end is just a code, that would change the marker ':•:' into a picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery replace matching text with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598048/jquery-replace-matching-text-with-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired result:

- use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to *set* the html. (Remember, it's no longer just text.)
- use `.replace(':•:', '<img src="http://lilpic.png" />')` instead of `.replace(':•:').html('<img src = "http://lilpic.png" />')`

Note: the image is not going to show up. (Because `http://lilpic.png` is not a link to an image.

```js
$("p").each(function() {

  if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(':•:', '<img src="http://lilpic.png" />'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Hello, this is some text :•:</p>
```

Also, there are some other improvements you can make to your code listed below.

```js
$("p").each(function() {
  // Use $(this) instead of $(this), as it's faster
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.children().length == 0) {
    //Replace ':•:' with an image and store it in a variable called `newText`
    var $newText = $this.text().replace(':•:', '<img src="http://lilpic.png" />');

    //Set the new text with the replace image
    $this.html($newText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello, this is some text :•:</p>

<p>Hello, this is some text :•:</p>
```

Comment: You are a wizard! Thank you so much, it works now. For some reason, when I tried this last time, it didn't work. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere.